# Shortcut method for value?value:""

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In REACT, I've to sometimes check for a variable if it exists. Then I  set it to value if that value exists or otherwise, I set it to a fallback value.

This ( name = value ? value: "" ) expression becomes very long.
Is there any alternative to this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
name = value ? value: ""
```

is (nearly always) equivalent to:

```
name = value || ''
```

But keep in mind that this will turn falsey (but not undefined) values like 0 and `NaN` into the empty string for `name`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to handle this as `name = name || ""` which can be shortened to `name ||= ""`

Comment: This would require OP to assign the value of `value` to `name` first

Comment: Whoops, yeah you're right I misread and missed the `value` part of the question. Was thinking in terms of a function's argument and making sure it's set, I up voted your answer instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use nullish coalescing operator for this.

```js
name = value ?? "";
```

But bear in mind the support for this feature isn't available on all browsers.

More info at MDN- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator